# Including libraries while compilation

Tags: include, gstreamer

to include say gstreamer libraries we need to use

```
 -lgstreamer-0.10
```

but if i want to manually specify the complete path.. which in this case is

```
/usr/bin/gstreamer-0.10
```

how can i do that

i tried doing the following, but this give me following errors:

```
-L/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10
```

Comment: compiler?  (seems to be gcc, but....)

Comment: yeah the compiler is gcc

Comment: `/usr/bin/gstreamer-0.10` - /usr/bin? You're keeping your libraries in  a bin directory? Or did you mean /usr/lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-L defines the search path so:

```
-L/usr/lib -lgstreamer-0.10
```

Note that if you don't use the expected style of library name ('lib' prefix - library name - '.a' suffix) the -L doesn't work.  Instead, just include the entire name of the library at the end of your compile line in the makefile.

```
cc -o tst tst.o /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10
```